# What's the difference between applying label vs rollback changeset

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfvc

In TFS 2012 What is the difference between getting a label vs rolling back a changeset.

What I'd like to do is go back to a version of a solution as it was at a certain point in time and just be able to run for testing purposes. I think what I'm looking for is applying a label to the solution. Right?

I'm a little confused with terminology Rollback, Get this version, apply a label.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "Get Specific Version". And tell it to fetch a specific changeset number or label name.

*Apply Label* actually places a new label in the repository. But doesn't get that version in your local workspace.

*Rollback* creates a compensating changeset at op top of the latest version which undoes the changes in the changeset you selected to roll back (essentially undo).

Comment: Is getting a specific changeset the same as getting a label? Let's say all things equal, say the changeset happen to occur the same time the label was applied, would there be any differences in the get?

Comment: If the label was created at the repository root, then it's the same. Its possible to change a label later and include newer or older versions of specific files. Not many people even know this is possible, so under most circumstances it's the same thing.